# What is the advantage of using a QueudSynchronizer to implement CountLatch

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

CountLatch is a thread control mechanism whereby a thread (or many threads) can block by calling `await()` on a CountLatch object, which will release when its `countDown()` method has been called some number of times.

Since I'm familiar with the concept of thread control with `wait()` and `notify()`, there is a (to me) obvious implementation of CountLatch, like this:

```
private volatile int count; // initialised in constructor

public synchronized void countDown() {
   count--;
   if(count <= 0) {
       notifyAll();
   }
}

public synchronized void await() throws InterruptedException {
    while(count > 0) {
        wait();
    }
}
```

However, Java 5 provides its own implementation, `java.util.concurrent.CountLatch` which uses an internal class extended from `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`.

```
private static final class Sync extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer {
    Sync(int count) {
        setState(count);
    }

    int getCount() {
        return getState();
    }

    protected int tryAcquireShared(int acquires) {
        return (getState() == 0) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    protected boolean tryReleaseShared(int releases) {
        // Decrement count; signal when transition to zero
        for (;;) {
            int c = getState();
            if (c == 0)
                return false;
            int nextc = c-1;
            if (compareAndSetState(c, nextc))
                return nextc == 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Java 5 CountLatch is essentially a wrapper around this Sync object:

- `countDown()` calls `sync.releaseShared(1)`
- `await()` calls `sync.acquireSharedInterruptibly(1)`

What is the advantage of this more complex approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference between your proposed approach and the JDK is that you are using locks whereas the `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` is lock free and uses Compare-And-Swap internally, which offers better performance under moderate contention.